# Which the cost of performance to use an interceptor in the java application?

Tags: java, interceptor, ejb-3.1

Which the cost of performance to use an interceptor in the java application (Only the cost for the intercept method, excluding processing within the interceptor)?

Comment: Which kind of answer do you expect? It depends on how the interceptor works (reflection or not?), on which machine it runs, on whether the JIT has optimized it or not...

Comment: is a ejb interceptor (ejb 3.1) in Jboss EAP 6.3